# Resonant powers for occultists who take the same implement twice

Tags: pathfinder-1e, implements, occult-magic, occultist

Under the Implements class ability for Occultists, it says the following:

> An occultist can select an implement school more than once in order to learn additional spells from the associated school.

And

> Every day, the occultist selects one item from that school’s list to be his implement for the day for each implement school he knows. The occultist needs only one such item to cast spells of the corresponding school, unless he selected that implement school multiple times, in which case he needs **one item for each set of spells gained from that school**.

Emphasis mine. Later, in the Mental Focus description it has this to say:

> An occultist can invest a portion of his mental focus into his chosen implements for the day... He can divide this mental focus between his implements in any way he desires

And later

> Once mental focus is invested inside an implement, the implement gains the resonant power of its implement school

So, if I take extra transmutation spells, I need two transmutation items - does that count as to transmutation implements? Can I invest mental focus in both separately, and get two of my stats buffed? Or do both items count as a single "implement" for the focus ability? Do I just need multiple items, but still just pick one of them each day? The wording here seems really ambiguous to me...

Answer (score 2):

The Idea of the rule stems from the Idea of the character.

**The History and RP:**

Think of an old movie or story with a strange person who dabbles in magic with a magic shop. When you ask to be able to do "_____" spell they grab a certain enchanted item, trinket, or potion. They dont have 12 - 14 of the same charms on the shelf. Each was made and crafted for a certain purpose OR the buyer had to come back later for the item when it was made.

What people forget is most rules are made so the Role Play of the character can be done like a myth or legend of a type of class. In this spirit you need two focuses (One for each set)

---

**The Rules:**

**Implements:**

You touched on them slightly with the question but here is the full set of rules

- One item/implement for the spell learned that day

> *Every day, the occultist selects one item from that school's list to be his implement for the day for each implement school he knows.*

- Multiple Items/implements

> *The occultist needs only one such item to cast spells of the corresponding school, **unless he selected that implement school multiple times**, in which case **he needs one item for each set** of spells gained from that school*

What this does is allow the character to have the extra spell slot at the casters level. Without the implement the casters spell is minimum level for the spell to be cast (EX: 2nd level spell needs 3rd level to cast so it will be 3rd )

> *If the occultist lacks the corresponding implement, he can attempt to cast the spell, but must succeed at a concentration check (DC = 20 + the spell's level) to do so.*

So you are allowed those spells with the items/implements. You will have to choose for each spell ....

> *Every day, the occultist selects one item from that school's list to be his implement for the day for each implement school he knows.*

an item and at that point have access to both spells even if same school...

> *The occultist needs only one such item to cast spells of the corresponding school, unless he selected that implement school multiple times*

Focuses:

These are easy and pretty well written once you know how many items you are suppose to have which was the main question but for the "TLDR"s

> *Once mental focus is invested inside an implement, the implement gains the resonant power of its implement school*

Meaning each implement needs to be focused on to cast the spell without penalties....like the Movies :)

---

**TLDR for the final question set:**

*So, if I take extra transmutation spells, I need two transmutation items*--
 **Yes**

*does that count as to transmutation implements?*--
 **Yes**

*Can I invest mental focus in both separately*--
**Yes**

*and get two of my stats buffed?*--
 **Yes**

*Or do both items count as a single "implement" for the focus ability?*--
 **No**

*Do I just need multiple items*--
 **Yes**

*but still just pick one of them each day*--
**No.. both are needed if you want the extra spells for each implement**

Hope this helps.